# Run QtVirtualKeyboard using QQuickWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtvirtualkeyboard, qquickwidget

I am trying to make the QtVirtualKeyboard example work with QQuickWidget instead of QQuickView. For QuickView, I use the following main.cpp code, which works fine for me:

```
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view(QString("qrc:/%2").arg(MAIN_QML));
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

I run into problems, when changing to QQuickWidgets with the following implementation of main.cpp:

```
#include <QQuickWidget>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickWidget w(QString("qrc:/%2").arg(MAIN_QML));
    w.setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

When I hit the input fields, the virtual keyboard shows up, but when I start typing at the keyboard, I get the message "input method is not set", which seems to be related to the input method plugin. No chars appear in the input fields.
Any ideas? The QML-code didn't change between the above variants of main.cpp

BTW: I am using Linux, gcc, Qt 5.9.0, EGLFS plugin

Thanks for any suggestions!

Regards,
Patrick

Comment: I did some further tests and the same code works with Qt 5.8.0, but fails on 5.9.0

Comment: Very strange bug: I used virtual keyboard normal in 5.12.x, then accidentally start to get these strange errors: `input method is not set`. Any updates how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution for QML looking through [`inputMethod` documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputmethod.html#update). Following workaround works for me:

```
TextArea {
    ...
    onActiveFocusChanged: {
        if(activeFocus) {
            Qt.inputMethod.update(Qt.ImQueryInput)
        }
    }
}
```

Works with other controls as well.

Of course `InputPanel` should be defined in `ApplicationWindow` like this:

```
ApplicationWindow {
...
    InputPanel {
        id: inputPanel
        ...
    }
}
```